# C# object oriented class structure

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose a hierarchical structure where B is a parent of C, D

I would like to define a method in B that C, and D will utilize, but it would reference other methods that would be defined in C and D

What is the best approach for that type of structure?

in pseudo code

```
class B
  int login()
      parseSite()

class C : B
  int parseSite()
      site specific logic goes here

class D : B
  int parseSite()
      site specific logic goes here
```

Comment: You can utilize [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: http://www.usmansidea.blogspot.com/2013/09/oop-concep-of-shadowing-definition-with.html

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an abstract method, for example:

```
class abstract B
{

    public int login()
    {
        parseSite();
    }

    protected abstract void parseSite();

}

class C : B
{

    protected override void parseSite()
    {

    }

}

class D : B
{

    protected override void parseSite()
    {

    }

}
```

The `login()` method is inherited in all the descendants of `B` and calls the `parseSite()` method which must be implemented in any descendant of `B`.

Comment: do you have to specify whether the abstract method is async?

Answer (score 0):

Make `parseSite` method abstract within `B` and override it in `C` and `D`.